# UIActivity With Multiple Actions

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am setting up my app with a few UIActivity Classes. The flow is that the user views an article, and clicks action button to pull up an UIActivityViewController.

```
- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Enter Password"];
    [dialog setMessage:@" "];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    dialog.tag = 5;

    dialog.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0].keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0].secureTextEntry = YES;

    CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
    [dialog setTransform: moveUp];
    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    }

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        UITextField *passwordField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:@"password"]) {
            [self composetheemail];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *oops = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Whoops" message:@"That password is incorrect.  Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [oops show];
            [oops release];
        }
    }
}

-(void)composetheemail {

    self.picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    self.picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [self.picker setSubject:@"App Test"];

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *churchemail = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@gmail.com"];
    [self.picker setToRecipients:churchemail];
    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"Sent from the App";
    [self.picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [picker release];
}
```

However, the method to compose the email never gets called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @mehulpatel I have done that. I put in NSLogs in the `clickedButtonAtIndex` and also the `composetheemail` method. It displays the log in console, but doesn't actually pull up the composeviewcontroller. I believe this is due to the UIActivity and how it is setup with the `- (UIViewController *)activityViewController {     NSLog(@"TEST3");          return self.picker; }`  part

Comment: Remember @mehulpatel this is a UIActivity class not a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller needs to explicitly conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol to have `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` be called.

In your view controller's @interface (usually in the `.h` file), you need to include the delegate like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Comment: I have done that.  I put in NSLogs in the `clickedButtonAtIndex` and also the `composetheemail` method.  It displays the log in console, but doesn't actually pull up the composeviewcontroller.  I believe this is due to the UIActivity and how it is setup with the `- (UIViewController *)activityViewController
{
    NSLog(@"TEST3");
    
    return self.picker;
}
` part

Comment: Remember this is a UIActivity class, not a UIViewController.

Comment: I imagine that you have a ```UIActivityViewController``` with your ```UIActivity```. You could subclass ```UIActivityViewController``` or make a category on it that conforms to the alert view delegate protocol.